# Is there enough Greenshine for every upgrade?

Tags: horizon-forbidden-west

*Horizon Forbidden West* introduced a new precious resource, [Greenshine](https://horizon.fandom.com/wiki/Greenshine), which is used to trade for rare items and as a upgrading material for some gears and weapons.

I suppose that there is a finite amount of this material in the world, hence my question: is there enough *Greenshine* to upgrade everything in the game, or should I prioritize specific gears?

The official wikia is pretty usless, it only states that:

> It is as-yet unclear if there is enough Greenshine to upgrade every item in the game that requires it. It is also unclear if rarer greenshine types (slabs) don't appear in earlier sections until the player has completed certain later quests.
> The total amount of Greenshine available, and the total amount of Greenshine needed, have not been calculated.

Did someone find out an answer?

(If the answer is no, I'm open to suggestions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done several playthroughs and I found that there is more than enough Greenshine for everything.

A lot of it is in deep water sites so you need to progress the main quests to gain the ability to reach it.

Many slabs are up high and are easier to reach when you get the ability to fly but nearly all of them can actually by reached by (difficult) climbing. You can actually see the first slab right at the start as Aloy descends into the Daunt.

So early on you may need to be careful - I upgrade the Nora Huntress outfit first, and maybe the Shock Warrior bow

Comment: I was afraid to upgrade uncommon gears using it, great to know!